# After death, can a soul travel to Earth to visit family, etc.?

Tags: soul, akhirah

After a person dies, can that person soul travel to earth to visit his family and stuff? I am asking this because I see a lot of passed away people in my dreams.

Answer (score 2):

Whether a dead person's soul travels back to Earth to visit family or friends is a matter of the unseen that only Allah knows that we would only come to know through revelations from Allah to His prophets or messengers. In the absence of any such revelations, one will not be able to tell the cause of seeing deceased people in one's dream.

The potential of meeting a deceased person in one's dream and the content of the dream being representative of reality at the time of the dream is not a concept that Islam denies.

In a long hadith in Sahih Muslim, Jabir ibn 'Abdullah narrated the story of Tufail ibn 'Amr ad-Dawsi and another man from his tribe, Daws, who both migrated to Medina. That man later committed suicide by cutting his wrists. Tufail saw that man in a dream with his cut hands wrapped. The man told Tufail that Allah had forgiven him because migrating to the Prophet ﷺ but his hands remained in the same state as he had damaged them. When Tufail told the Prophet ﷺ about his dream, the Prophet ﷺ supplicated to Allah for his hands to be pardoned, too. This means that the Prophet ﷺ did not reject the idea that the dream might have been a true vision:

> عَنْ جَابِرٍ، أَنَّ الطُّفَيْلَ بْنَ عَمْرٍو الدَّوْسِيَّ، أَتَى النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَقَالَ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ هَلْ لَكَ فِي حِصْنٍ حَصِينٍ وَمَنَعَةٍ - قَالَ حِصْنٌ كَانَ لِدَوْسٍ فِي الْجَاهِلِيَّةِ - فَأَبَى ذَلِكَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم لِلَّذِي ذَخَرَ اللَّهُ لِلأَنْصَارِ فَلَمَّا هَاجَرَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم إِلَى الْمَدِينَةِ هَاجَرَ إِلَيْهِ الطُّفَيْلُ بْنُ عَمْرٍو وَهَاجَرَ مَعَهُ رَجُلٌ مِنْ قَوْمِهِ فَاجْتَوَوُا الْمَدِينَةَ فَمَرِضَ فَجَزِعَ فَأَخَذَ مَشَاقِصَ لَهُ فَقَطَعَ بِهَا بَرَاجِمَهُ فَشَخَبَتْ يَدَاهُ حَتَّى مَاتَ فَرَآهُ الطُّفَيْلُ بْنُ عَمْرٍو فِي مَنَامِهِ فَرَآهُ وَهَيْئَتُهُ حَسَنَةٌ وَرَآهُ مُغَطِّيًا يَدَيْهِ فَقَالَ لَهُ مَا صَنَعَ بِكَ رَبُّكَ فَقَالَ غَفَرَ لِي بِهِجْرَتِي إِلَى نَبِيِّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَقَالَ مَا لِي أَرَاكَ مُغَطِّيًا يَدَيْكَ قَالَ قِيلَ لِي لَنْ نُصْلِحَ مِنْكَ مَا أَفْسَدْتَ.‏ فَقَصَّهَا الطُّفَيْلُ عَلَى رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم.‏ فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم: ‏ اللَّهُمَّ وَلِيَدَيْهِ فَاغْفِرْ
>
> It is narrated on the authority of Jabir that Tufail son of Amr al-Dausi came to the Apostle (ﷺ) and said: Do you need strong, fortified protection? The tribe of Daus had a fort in the pre-Islamic days. The Apostle (ﷺ) declined this offer since it (the privilege of protecting the Holy Prophet) had already been reserved for the Ansar. When the Apostle (ﷺ) migrated to Medina, Tufail son of Amr also migrated to that place, and there also migrated along with him a man of his tribe. But the climate of Medina did not suit him, and he fell sick. He felt very uneasy. So he took hold of an iron head of an arrow and cut his finger-joints. The blood streamed forth from his hands, till he died. Tufail son of Amr saw him in a dream. His state was good and he saw him with his hands wrapped. He (Tufail) said to him: What treatment did your Allah accord to you? He replied. Allah granted me pardon for my migration to the Apostle (ﷺ): He (Tufail) again said: What is this that I see you wrapping up your hands? He replied: I was told (by Allah): We would not set right anything of yours which you damaged yourself. Tufail narrated this (dream) to the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ). Upon this, he prayed: "O Allah, grant pardon even to his hands."
>
> <sub>— [Sahih Muslim, Book 1, Hadith 218](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/1/218)</sub>

[Ibn Qayyim al-Jawziyya - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Qayyim_al-Jawziyya) deduced from this that there is a possibility that the souls of people who are alive and those who are deceased meet during sleep (see *Al-Ru'ā* [pp. 101](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32813/99#p4), Arabic only).

It is to be noted, however, that there is no evidence that any such meetings of souls may be willfully initiated by a living person at any specific time or place, and that if a dream is observed, there is no way of telling whether that dream was a true vision or from Satan or a mixture of false dreams.

Answer (score 0):

Dead person's soul doesn't comes back to earth as Allah says in the Quran SURAH 39 Verse 42 "Allah takes the souls of the dead and the souls of the living while they sleep– He keeps hold of those whose death He has ordained and sends the others back until their appointed time– there truly are signs in this for those who reflect."

Answer (score -1):

In the name of God, the Most Gracious, Most Merciful.

**Answer:**

It is possible that spirit of a deceased person can travel to earth to see his or her family and stuff.

Ibnu’l Qayyim says:

> ”Meeting the dead in the dreams, exchanging news with them, their giving some information like, there is a treasure there or there is this over that place or this will happen like that or you will come to us at that particular time and this kind of information turning out true represent the reality of such meeting.” (35)

There’s a saying to what you say, that you see dead people in your dream.

> ”According to the narrations, Sa’b b. Jassama and Awf b. Malik from the Honored Companions became brothers and promised each other to keep in touch after death. After a while, Sa’b died. Awf saw Sa’b come to him as if he was alive in his dream and he asked Sa’b about how the questioning went. He replied it was going well for then and thanked God. Meanwhile, Awf asked Sa’b the reason why there was a black spot on his chest. He replied he borrowed ten dirhams from a Jewish person and saying the place where the money was, he asked that money to be returned to that man. Also, he reported that his cat was dead and his daughter was going to die soon and these all turn out to come into reality. When the morning broke and Awf went to his friend’s house, he saw the money was in the place where it was informed to be and he took it to return to the Jewish man. He asked the Jewish man if his friend borrowed money from him and the Jewish man confirmed by also giving the exact quantity of the money. Understanding that what he saw in his dream was real and complying with the will of his friend, Awf gave the money to the Jewish man.” (36)

Erzurumlu Ibrahim Hakki says:

> ”Seeing the dead in good or bad situations in the dream is knowing the exact situation they are in. This is to show the situation of the dead or to make stay awake.” (34), He pointed out that seeing the dead in the dreams are of real dreams.”

So, it is possible that the spirits can visit the alive by God’s permission and will. But you have to be very careful what you dream because, it could be a trick.

Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah (may God have mercy on him) said:

> ”The jinn may appear in human or animal form; they may appear in the form of snakes, scorpions and so on; or in the form of camels, cattle, sheep, horses, mules and donkeys; or in the form of birds. They may also appear in human form, as the Shaytaan came to Quraysh in the form of Suraaqah ibn Maalik ibn Ja‘sham, when they wanted to go out to Badr.”

Secondly, you have to be very careful of what you dream. Every night before or every time you go to sleep, recite “The Thorne Verse” (Ayat Al Kursi) and perform every day correctly prayers, so that you can be sure that what you dream is not from Jinn nor from the devil but from God Almighty.

God, may He be exalted, says (interpretation of the meaning):

> ”And (remember) when Shaitan (Satan) made their (evil) deeds seem fair to them and said, ‘No one of mankind can overcome you this Day (of the battle of Badr) and verily, I am your neighbour (for each and every help).’ But when the two forces came in sight of each other, he ran away and said ‘Verily, I have nothing to do with you. Verily! I see what you see not. Verily! I fear God for God is Severe in punishment’”

Hadith from Sahih al-Bukhari:

> ”If one of you sees a dream that he likes, it is from God. He should praise God for it and he should relate it to others. If he sees what he dislikes, it is from Satan. He should seek refuge in God from it and not mention it to anyone. Thereby, it will not harm him.”

If those people you see in your dreams that have deceased, it means that they are believers and have high taqwa in this world in God’s eye. And they are granted permission by God more often like twice a week or so, while some may be allowed just once a year or even less. Also disbelievers are given permission to visit their relatives so that they may squirm within that these people will also meet the same fate they have of having done shirk. But if you want to see someone from the dead you should Perform Wudhū and sleep on your right, recite Tasbīh Fātimah (SA) then recite this Supplication:

> ”Allāhumā Antal hayy al-ladhī lā yūsafu w'al-īmana ya'arifu minhu badā'atil al-ashyāu wa ilayka ta'ūdu akbal minhā kuntu maljā'a wa mā adabar minhā lam yakunlahū maljā'un walā manjā minka illā ilayka, fa as-aluka bi lā ilāha illā anta, wa as-aluka Bismillah ar-Rahmān ar-Rahīm, wa bihaqqi habbebika Mohammadin (Sal Allahu Alayhi wa Ālihi) Sayyid an-Nabiyyīn, wa bihaqqi Ali-yin khayr al-wasiyyīn, wa bihaqqi Fātimata Sayyidat an-Nisā al-Ālamīn, wa bihaqq al-Hasani w'al-Husayn al-ladhīna ajalta humā Sayyida ash-Shabābi Ahl al-Jannati (Alayhi Ajma'īn Salāmu), an tusalli Alā Mohammadin wa āli Mohammad wa in turiyanī mayyiti fi al-hāl al-Latī huwa fīhā.”

I’ll give few examples so that I can clarify

Muhammad’s (pbuh) meeting with other prophets while he was still alive is something possible to happen. And it is of no difficulty for God to do this. This happened when God made him meet them and in the night of Miraj, Muhammad (pbuh) met the spirits of the Prophets at Al-Masjid al-Aqsa while he was awake. Later, some reports prove that he met some of them in the heavens. (29)

Also, in an another hadith narrated by Umar (may God be pleased with him), the Prophet (pbuh) reported that Moses (pbuh) prayed to God to let him talk to Adam (pbuh) and God let Moses (pbuh) meet and talk to Adam (pbuh), when he was still alive and awake.(30)

So in here, we learn that nothing can be impossible, and it might be God’s will so that you can see the spirits of the deceased people.

I hope that this is a good answer.

And God knows best.

---

**Link sources:**

1) http://questionsonislam.com/question/can-dead-person-contact-actual-world-can-they-see-people-who-visit-their-graves.

Comment: Why do I got a downvote?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Alex, I don't know why it's voted down.

Answer (score -1):

Soul can't travel long journey it can't pass ocean soul can travel only short distance because they don't have medium to travel so if you live near where you're loved one's died than sure you feel your loved one's soul is near to you .

Answer (score -1):

The Messenger of God (peace be upon him said) said, “Actions are presented to God on Mondays and Thursdays, and presented to Prophets, fathers, and mothers on Fridays. They will rejoice at the good works and their faces will increase in brightness. So fear God, and don’t hurt your dead.”

(Al-Hakim At-Tirmidhi : Nawadir Al-Usul)

The Messenger of God, peace be upon him said, “Your actions are presented to your dead relatives and clans. If they see goodness in it, they will rejoice at it, and if they see other than that, they will say, “Oh God! Do not let them die until you guided them as you have guided us!”

(Imam Ahmad, Al-Hakim Tirmidhi : Nawadir Al-Usul)